# creating a certain number of table rows programmatically

Tags: android

I have an activity which contains a table layout, I know how to set up the table layout, with the required number of rows.
But I want the user to be able to define the number of rows that are created on the page.
Here is how I intend to go about it. When the user navigates to the page, an alert dialog that collects the number of rows he wants to create pops up, then he inserts a value and the value is used to generate the required number of rows.
I can find my way up to creating the dialog and collecting the number but I don't know how to use it to generate the rows. 
Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is pretty straightforward. Try this:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

    for (int i=0; i<nrFromDialog; i++ ){

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Row" + i);
        row.addView(text);

        table.addView(row); 
    }
```

Good luck!